# Could not find or load main class in bash

Tags: java, bash, class

I used jflex to generate a Java class and now I want to use it to get lexical analysis of a .txt file. The Java Class begins like this:

```
       /* The following code was generated by JFlex 1.6.1 */

/**
 * This class is a scanner generated by 
 * <a href="http://www.jflex.de/">JFlex</a> 1.6.1
 * from the specification file <tt>patch.flex</tt>
 */
public class Patch {

  /** This character denotes the end of file */
  public static final int YYEOF = -1;

  /** initial size of the lookahead buffer */
  private static final int ZZ_BUFFERSIZE = 16384;

  /** lexical states */
  public static final int YYINITIAL = 0;

  /**
   * ZZ_LEXSTATE[l] is the state in the DFA for the lexical state l
   * ZZ_LEXSTATE[l+1] is the state in the DFA for the lexical state l
   *                  at the beginning of a line
   * l is of the form l = 2*k, k a non negative integer
   */
  private static final int ZZ_LEXSTATE[] = { 
     0, 0
  };

  /** 
   * Translates characters to character classes
   */
  private static final String ZZ_CMAP_PACKED = 
    "\141\0\1\1\1\2\1\3\1\4\uffff\0\uffff\0\uffff\0\uffff\0\uffff\0\uffff\0\uffff\0\uffff\0\uffff\0\uffff\0\uffff\0\uffff\0\uffff\0\uffff\0\uffff\0\uffff\0\uffab\0";

  /** 
   * Translates characters to character classes
   */
  private static final char [] ZZ_CMAP = zzUnpackCMap(ZZ_CMAP_PACKED);

  /** 
   * Translates DFA states to action switch labels.
   */
  private static final int [] ZZ_ACTION = zzUnpackAction();

  private static final String ZZ_ACTION_PACKED_0 =
    "\1\0\2\1\3\0\1\2\2\0\2\2";

  private static int [] zzUnpackAction() {
    int [] result = new int[11];
    int offset = 0;
    offset = zzUnpackAction(ZZ_ACTION_PACKED_0, offset, result);
    return result;
  }

  private static int zzUnpackAction(String packed, int offset, int [] result) {
    int i = 0;       /* index in packed string  */
    int j = offset;  /* index in unpacked array */
    int l = packed.length();
    while (i < l) {
      int count = packed.charAt(i++);
      int value = packed.charAt(i++);
      do result[j++] = value; while (--count > 0);
    }
    return j;
  }


  /** 
   * Translates a state to a row index in the transition table
   */
  private static final int [] ZZ_ROWMAP = zzUnpackRowMap();

  private static final String ZZ_ROWMAP_PACKED_0 =
    "\0\0\0\5\0\12\0\12\0\17\0\24\0\31\0\36"+
    "\0\31\0\5\0\36";

  private static int [] zzUnpackRowMap() {
    int [] result = new int[11];
    int offset = 0;
    offset = zzUnpackRowMap(ZZ_ROWMAP_PACKED_0, offset, result);
    return result;
  }

  private static int zzUnpackRowMap(String packed, int offset, int [] result) {
    int i = 0;  /* index in packed string  */
    int j = offset;  /* index in unpacked array */
    int l = packed.length();
    while (i < l) {
      int high = packed.charAt(i++) << 16;
      result[j++] = high | packed.charAt(i++);
    }
    return j;
  }

  /** 
   * The transition table of the DFA
   */
  private static final int [] ZZ_TRANS = zzUnpackTrans();

  private static final String ZZ_TRANS_PACKED_0 =
    "\1\2\1\3\3\2\6\0\1\4\1\5\1\6\3\0"+
    "\1\5\1\7\2\0\1\10\1\0\1\6\4\0\1\11"+
    "\1\12\1\0\1\13\3\0";

  private static int [] zzUnpackTrans() {
    int [] result = new int[35];
    int offset = 0;
    offset = zzUnpackTrans(ZZ_TRANS_PACKED_0, offset, result);
    return result;
  }

  private static int zzUnpackTrans(String packed, int offset, int [] result) {
    int i = 0;       /* index in packed string  */
    int j = offset;  /* index in unpacked array */
    int l = packed.length();
    while (i < l) {
      int count = packed.charAt(i++);
      int value = packed.charAt(i++);
      value--;
      do result[j++] = value; while (--count > 0);
    }
    return j;
  }


  /* error codes */
  private static final int ZZ_UNKNOWN_ERROR = 0;
  private static final int ZZ_NO_MATCH = 1;
  private static final int ZZ_PUSHBACK_2BIG = 2;

  /* error messages for the codes above */
  private static final String ZZ_ERROR_MSG[] = {
    "Unknown internal scanner error",
    "Error: could not match input",
    "Error: pushback value was too large"
  };

  /**
   * ZZ_ATTRIBUTE[aState] contains the attributes of state <code>aState</code>
   */
  private static final int [] ZZ_ATTRIBUTE = zzUnpackAttribute();

  private static final String ZZ_ATTRIBUTE_PACKED_0 =
    "\1\0\1\11\1\1\3\0\1\1\2\0\1\11\1\1";

  private static int [] zzUnpackAttribute() {
    int [] result = new int[11];
    int offset = 0;
    offset = zzUnpackAttribute(ZZ_ATTRIBUTE_PACKED_0, offset, result);
    return result;
  }

  private static int zzUnpackAttribute(String packed, int offset, int [] result) {
    int i = 0;       /* index in packed string  */
    int j = offset;  /* index in unpacked array */
    int l = packed.length();
    while (i < l) {
      int count = packed.charAt(i++);
      int value = packed.charAt(i++);
      do result[j++] = value; while (--count > 0);
    }
    return j;
  }

  /** the input device */
  private java.io.Reader zzReader;

  /** the current state of the DFA */
  private int zzState;

  /** the current lexical state */
  private int zzLexicalState = YYINITIAL;

  /** this buffer contains the current text to be matched and is
      the source of the yytext() string */
  private char zzBuffer[] = new char[ZZ_BUFFERSIZE];

  /** the textposition at the last accepting state */
  private int zzMarkedPos;

  /** the current text position in the buffer */
  private int zzCurrentPos;

  /** startRead marks the beginning of the yytext() string in the buffer */
  private int zzStartRead;

  /** endRead marks the last character in the buffer, that has been read
      from input */
  private int zzEndRead;

  /** number of newlines encountered up to the start of the matched text */
  private int yyline;

  /** the number of characters up to the start of the matched text */
  private int yychar;

  /**
   * the number of characters from the last newline up to the start of the 
   * matched text
   */
  private int yycolumn;

  /** 
   * zzAtBOL == true <=> the scanner is currently at the beginning of a line
   */
  private boolean zzAtBOL = true;

  /** zzAtEOF == true <=> the scanner is at the EOF */
  private boolean zzAtEOF;

  /** denotes if the user-EOF-code has already been executed */
  private boolean zzEOFDone;

  /** 
   * The number of occupied positions in zzBuffer beyond zzEndRead.
   * When a lead/high surrogate has been read from the input stream
   * into the final zzBuffer position, this will have a value of 1;
   * otherwise, it will have a value of 0.
   */
  private int zzFinalHighSurrogate = 0;


  /**
   * Creates a new scanner
   *
   * @param   in  the java.io.Reader to read input from.
   */
  public Patch(java.io.Reader in) {
    this.zzReader = in;
  }


  /** 
   * Unpacks the compressed character translation table.
   *
   * @param packed   the packed character translation table
   * @return         the unpacked character translation table
   */
  private static char [] zzUnpackCMap(String packed) {
    char [] map = new char[0x110000];
    int i = 0;  /* index in packed string  */
    int j = 0;  /* index in unpacked array */
    while (i < 44) {
      int  count = packed.charAt(i++);
      char value = packed.charAt(i++);
      do map[j++] = value; while (--count > 0);
    }
    return map;
  }


  /**
   * Refills the input buffer.
   *
   * @return      <code>false</code>, iff there was new input.
   * 
   * @exception   java.io.IOException  if any I/O-Error occurs
   */
  private boolean zzRefill() throws java.io.IOException {

    /* first: make room (if you can) */
    if (zzStartRead > 0) {
      zzEndRead += zzFinalHighSurrogate;
      zzFinalHighSurrogate = 0;
      System.arraycopy(zzBuffer, zzStartRead,
                       zzBuffer, 0,
                       zzEndRead-zzStartRead);

      /* translate stored positions */
      zzEndRead-= zzStartRead;
      zzCurrentPos-= zzStartRead;
      zzMarkedPos-= zzStartRead;
      zzStartRead = 0;
    }

    /* is the buffer big enough? */
    if (zzCurrentPos >= zzBuffer.length - zzFinalHighSurrogate) {
      /* if not: blow it up */
      char newBuffer[] = new char[zzBuffer.length*2];
      System.arraycopy(zzBuffer, 0, newBuffer, 0, zzBuffer.length);
      zzBuffer = newBuffer;
      zzEndRead += zzFinalHighSurrogate;
      zzFinalHighSurrogate = 0;
    }

    /* fill the buffer with new input */
    int requested = zzBuffer.length - zzEndRead;
    int numRead = zzReader.read(zzBuffer, zzEndRead, requested);

    /* not supposed to occur according to specification of java.io.Reader */
    if (numRead == 0) {
      throw new java.io.IOException("Reader returned 0 characters. See JFlex examples for workaround.");
    }
    if (numRead > 0) {
      zzEndRead += numRead;
      /* If numRead == requested, we might have requested to few chars to
         encode a full Unicode character. We assume that a Reader would
         otherwise never return half characters. */
      if (numRead == requested) {
        if (Character.isHighSurrogate(zzBuffer[zzEndRead - 1])) {
          --zzEndRead;
          zzFinalHighSurrogate = 1;
        }
      }
      /* potentially more input available */
      return false;
    }

    /* numRead < 0 ==> end of stream */
    return true;
  }


  /**
   * Closes the input stream.
   */
  public final void yyclose() throws java.io.IOException {
    zzAtEOF = true;            /* indicate end of file */
    zzEndRead = zzStartRead;  /* invalidate buffer    */

    if (zzReader != null)
      zzReader.close();
  }


  /**
   * Resets the scanner to read from a new input stream.
   * Does not close the old reader.
   *
   * All internal variables are reset, the old input stream 
   * <b>cannot</b> be reused (internal buffer is discarded and lost).
   * Lexical state is set to <tt>ZZ_INITIAL</tt>.
   *
   * Internal scan buffer is resized down to its initial length, if it has grown.
   *
   * @param reader   the new input stream 
   */
  public final void yyreset(java.io.Reader reader) {
    zzReader = reader;
    zzAtBOL  = true;
    zzAtEOF  = false;
    zzEOFDone = false;
    zzEndRead = zzStartRead = 0;
    zzCurrentPos = zzMarkedPos = 0;
    zzFinalHighSurrogate = 0;
    yyline = yychar = yycolumn = 0;
    zzLexicalState = YYINITIAL;
    if (zzBuffer.length > ZZ_BUFFERSIZE)
      zzBuffer = new char[ZZ_BUFFERSIZE];
  }


  /**
   * Returns the current lexical state.
   */
  public final int yystate() {
    return zzLexicalState;
  }


  /**
   * Enters a new lexical state
   *
   * @param newState the new lexical state
   */
  public final void yybegin(int newState) {
    zzLexicalState = newState;
  }


  /**
   * Returns the text matched by the current regular expression.
   */
  public final String yytext() {
    return new String( zzBuffer, zzStartRead, zzMarkedPos-zzStartRead );
  }


  /**
   * Returns the character at position <tt>pos</tt> from the 
   * matched text. 
   * 
   * It is equivalent to yytext().charAt(pos), but faster
   *
   * @param pos the position of the character to fetch. 
   *            A value from 0 to yylength()-1.
   *
   * @return the character at position pos
   */
  public final char yycharat(int pos) {
    return zzBuffer[zzStartRead+pos];
  }


  /**
   * Returns the length of the matched text region.
   */
  public final int yylength() {
    return zzMarkedPos-zzStartRead;
  }


  /**
   * Reports an error that occured while scanning.
   *
   * In a wellformed scanner (no or only correct usage of 
   * yypushback(int) and a match-all fallback rule) this method 
   * will only be called with things that "Can't Possibly Happen".
   * If this method is called, something is seriously wrong
   * (e.g. a JFlex bug producing a faulty scanner etc.).
   *
   * Usual syntax/scanner level error handling should be done
   * in error fallback rules.
   *
   * @param   errorCode  the code of the errormessage to display
   */
  private void zzScanError(int errorCode) {
    String message;
    try {
      message = ZZ_ERROR_MSG[errorCode];
    }
    catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
      message = ZZ_ERROR_MSG[ZZ_UNKNOWN_ERROR];
    }

    throw new Error(message);
  } 


  /**
   * Pushes the specified amount of characters back into the input stream.
   *
   * They will be read again by then next call of the scanning method
   *
   * @param number  the number of characters to be read again.
   *                This number must not be greater than yylength()!
   */
  public void yypushback(int number)  {
    if ( number > yylength() )
      zzScanError(ZZ_PUSHBACK_2BIG);

    zzMarkedPos -= number;
  }


  /**
   * Resumes scanning until the next regular expression is matched,
   * the end of input is encountered or an I/O-Error occurs.
   *
   * @return      the next token
   * @exception   java.io.IOException  if any I/O-Error occurs
   */
  public int yylex() throws java.io.IOException {
    int zzInput;
    int zzAction;

    // cached fields:
    int zzCurrentPosL;
    int zzMarkedPosL;
    int zzEndReadL = zzEndRead;
    char [] zzBufferL = zzBuffer;
    char [] zzCMapL = ZZ_CMAP;

    int [] zzTransL = ZZ_TRANS;
    int [] zzRowMapL = ZZ_ROWMAP;
    int [] zzAttrL = ZZ_ATTRIBUTE;

    while (true) {
      zzMarkedPosL = zzMarkedPos;

      boolean zzR = false;
      int zzCh;
      int zzCharCount;
      for (zzCurrentPosL = zzStartRead  ;
           zzCurrentPosL < zzMarkedPosL ;
           zzCurrentPosL += zzCharCount ) {
        zzCh = Character.codePointAt(zzBufferL, zzCurrentPosL, zzMarkedPosL);
        zzCharCount = Character.charCount(zzCh);
        switch (zzCh) {
        case '\u000B':
        case '\u000C':
        case '\u0085':
        case '\u2028':
        case '\u2029':
          yyline++;
          yycolumn = 0;
          zzR = false;
          break;
        case '\r':
          yyline++;
          yycolumn = 0;
          zzR = true;
          break;
        case '\n':
          if (zzR)
            zzR = false;
          else {
            yyline++;
            yycolumn = 0;
          }
          break;
        default:
          zzR = false;
          yycolumn += zzCharCount;
        }
      }

      if (zzR) {
        // peek one character ahead if it is \n (if we have counted one line too much)
        boolean zzPeek;
        if (zzMarkedPosL < zzEndReadL)
          zzPeek = zzBufferL[zzMarkedPosL] == '\n';
        else if (zzAtEOF)
          zzPeek = false;
        else {
          boolean eof = zzRefill();
          zzEndReadL = zzEndRead;
          zzMarkedPosL = zzMarkedPos;
          zzBufferL = zzBuffer;
          if (eof) 
            zzPeek = false;
          else 
            zzPeek = zzBufferL[zzMarkedPosL] == '\n';
        }
        if (zzPeek) yyline--;
      }
      zzAction = -1;

      zzCurrentPosL = zzCurrentPos = zzStartRead = zzMarkedPosL;

      zzState = ZZ_LEXSTATE[zzLexicalState];

      // set up zzAction for empty match case:
      int zzAttributes = zzAttrL[zzState];
      if ( (zzAttributes & 1) == 1 ) {
        zzAction = zzState;
      }


      zzForAction: {
        while (true) {

          if (zzCurrentPosL < zzEndReadL) {
            zzInput = Character.codePointAt(zzBufferL, zzCurrentPosL, zzEndReadL);
            zzCurrentPosL += Character.charCount(zzInput);
          }
          else if (zzAtEOF) {
            zzInput = YYEOF;
            break zzForAction;
          }
          else {
            // store back cached positions
            zzCurrentPos  = zzCurrentPosL;
            zzMarkedPos   = zzMarkedPosL;
            boolean eof = zzRefill();
            // get translated positions and possibly new buffer
            zzCurrentPosL  = zzCurrentPos;
            zzMarkedPosL   = zzMarkedPos;
            zzBufferL      = zzBuffer;
            zzEndReadL     = zzEndRead;
            if (eof) {
              zzInput = YYEOF;
              break zzForAction;
            }
            else {
              zzInput = Character.codePointAt(zzBufferL, zzCurrentPosL, zzEndReadL);
              zzCurrentPosL += Character.charCount(zzInput);
            }
          }
          int zzNext = zzTransL[ zzRowMapL[zzState] + zzCMapL[zzInput] ];
          if (zzNext == -1) break zzForAction;
          zzState = zzNext;

          zzAttributes = zzAttrL[zzState];
          if ( (zzAttributes & 1) == 1 ) {
            zzAction = zzState;
            zzMarkedPosL = zzCurrentPosL;
            if ( (zzAttributes & 8) == 8 ) break zzForAction;
          }

        }
      }

      // store back cached position
      zzMarkedPos = zzMarkedPosL;

      if (zzInput == YYEOF && zzStartRead == zzCurrentPos) {
        zzAtEOF = true;
        return YYEOF;
      }
      else {
        switch (zzAction < 0 ? zzAction : ZZ_ACTION[zzAction]) {
          case 1: 
            { System.out.print(yytext());
            }
          case 3: break;
          case 2: 
            { System.out.println("***found match");
            }
          case 4: break;
          default:
            zzScanError(ZZ_NO_MATCH);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * Runs the scanner on input files.
   *
   * This is a standalone scanner, it will print any unmatched
   * text to System.out unchanged.
   *
   * @param argv   the command line, contains the filenames to run
   *               the scanner on.
   */
  public static void main(String argv[]) {
    if (argv.length == 0) {
      System.out.println("Usage : java Patch [ --encoding <name> ] <inputfile(s)>");
    }
    else {
      int firstFilePos = 0;
      String encodingName = "UTF-8";
      if (argv[0].equals("--encoding")) {
        firstFilePos = 2;
        encodingName = argv[1];
        try {
          java.nio.charset.Charset.forName(encodingName); // Side-effect: is encodingName valid? 
        } catch (Exception e) {
          System.out.println("Invalid encoding '" + encodingName + "'");
          return;
        }
      }
      for (int i = firstFilePos; i < argv.length; i++) {
        Patch scanner = null;
        try {
          java.io.FileInputStream stream = new java.io.FileInputStream(argv[i]);
          java.io.Reader reader = new java.io.InputStreamReader(stream, encodingName);
          scanner = new Patch(reader);
          while ( !scanner.zzAtEOF ) scanner.yylex();
        }
        catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException e) {
          System.out.println("File not found : \""+argv[i]+"\"");
        }
        catch (java.io.IOException e) {
          System.out.println("IO error scanning file \""+argv[i]+"\"");
          System.out.println(e);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
          System.out.println("Unexpected exception:");
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }
  }


}
```

The shell keep giving me the error

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Patch
```

when I use the command like:

```
java Patch SearchText.txt
```

Besides, there's no error when I run:

```
javac Patch.java
```

I tried to set the path explicitly:

```
    java -cp. Patch SearchText.txt
```

and got something like this:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1348\cocoasubrtf170
{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;}
{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}
\margl1440\margr1440\vieww10800\viewh8400\viewkind0
\pard\tx720\tx1440\tx2160\tx2880\tx3600\tx4320\tx5040\tx5760\tx6480\tx7200\tx7920\tx8640\pardirnatural

\f0\fs24 \cf0 a+b+c+d}AmbertekiMacBook-Air:ADS4 amber95$ java Patch SearchText.txt
Error: Could not find or load main class Patch
```

Comment: I'm not sure what this have to do with [tag:bash]

Comment: @andlrc oh I am just trying to say I am running this in mac terminal

Comment: What package is the Patch.java in?

Comment: It's not in a package. just a .java file @Sri Harsha Chilakapati

Comment: Can I take a look at the class completely?

Comment: Do you see a ```Patch.class``` file?

Comment: @Jorn Vernee Yes, there is a Patch.class file in the same directory after javac patch.java

Comment: Try explicitly setting the class path: ```java -cp . Patch SearchText.txt```

Comment: @Jorn Vernee Look at my post. I edited it again

Comment: @Sri Harsha Chilakapati Yes, I posted the complete class in my post now

Comment: Looks like it worked. I don't know what output to expect from that program, but that kinda looks like LaTeX to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
java -cp ./ Patch file.txt
```

Comment: I think it  worked. just that i still need to fix my output. Thanks